# What does this c code do and how to get to the access granted

Tags: c

This is the `c` code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <gcrypt.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pwd.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    void access_granted() {

    }

    struct permission {
        int flags[10];
        int access_1;
        int access_2;
    };

    int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        struct permission data;
        int i;
        data.access_1 = 0;
        data.access_2 = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.flags[i] = 0;
        }

        if(argc > 1) {
            data.flags[atoi(argv[1])] = 1;
        }

        if(argc > 2) {
            data.flags[atoi(argv[2])] = 0;
        }

        if(argc > 3) {
            data.flags[atoi(argv[3])] = 1;
        }


        if(data.access_1 == 1 && data.access_2 == 0 && data.flags[5] == 1) {
            access_granted();
        } else {
            printf("Input sequence incorrect. Access denied.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Can someone help me? With getting to the access granted? A thanks to the one that can help me.
This is a program that a friend gave me to crack(I am not that good with c and I would like some help)

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: How to pass:  if(data.access_1 == 1 && data.access_2 == 0 && data.flags[5] == 1) {
            access_granted();
        }

Comment: Where is the problem ? What dou you want to do ? Your question is totally unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the program with parameters 10 11 5 and you'll get to access_granted. But it may depend on how your compiler aligns variables data in memory.

Comment: you did indeed find the secret code thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this part:

```
    if(data.access_1 == 1 && data.access_2 == 0 && data.flags[5] == 1) {
        access_granted();
    } else {
        printf("Input sequence incorrect. Access denied.\n");
    }
```

to be:

```
    access_granted();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this (terribly written) piece of code will never call access_granted(), regardless of the input sequence, because data.access_1 is set to zero from the start, and it remains zero until the main condition statement.

By the way, ever heard of memset? You should look it up viz. your loop which sets all the data.flags to zero.

Comment: That's not true. This code will call access_granted() if a particular buffer overrun is induced, leading to undefined behavior triggering overwriting values assumed to be past the buffer.